# How to determin the matrix of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

let $U = \mathbb{C}^2$ and $V = \mathbb{C}^2$, viewed as vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. Let f : U → V be the linear map represented by the matrix

$(2i,1+4i)$

with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$.
(The standard bases are $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ and $\{1\}$ respectively.)

Now view U and V as vector spaces over $\Bbb{R}$. Determine the matrix of the same map f : U →V as above with respect to the ordered bases B = $\{(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)\}$ and C = $\{1,i\}$.

I've already proved that that B and C are bases of U and V, i'm not sure yet how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\beta=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\gamma=\{1\}$, and by the assumption that 
$[f]_{\beta}^\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}2i&1+4i\end{pmatrix}$. Then
\begin{align*}
f\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}2i&1+4i\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=2i=0\cdot1+2\cdot i\\
f\begin{pmatrix}i\\0\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}2i&1+4i\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}i\\0\end{pmatrix}=-2=-2\cdot1+0\cdot i\\
f\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}2i&1+4i\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=1+4i=1\cdot1+4\cdot i\\
f\begin{pmatrix}0\\i\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}2i&1+4i\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\i\end{pmatrix}=-4+i=-4\cdot1+1\cdot i
\end{align*}
So the matrix representation should be
\begin{align*}
[f]_B^C=\begin{pmatrix}0&-2&1&-4\\2&0&4&1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I see, thank you for the method, if you weren't given the original linear map, is there a method you could use to work it out?

Comment: @HELP if the original matrix representation of the linear map is not under two standard ordered bases, then we should use the change of bases method to get the appropriate entries.